# Rstudio-Empty ggplot in a function

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a function called `plot.medals2` that has an input that includes a variable named start and a variable named finish. Both variables are numbers and I want that in the event that start is bigger than finish the function will stop running and draw an empty `ggplot` like the one i attached here.[image]

This is the part of the code that is supposed to take care of that:

```
plot.medals2 <- function(code,start,finish,medalsvec) {
  if(start>finish) {  #years not make sense return empty drawing
    ggplot() + ylab('medals won') + xlab('year') +
      ggtitle(paste('Medals by',"",countries.df[countries.df$country_id==code,]$country_name,',',"",finish,'-',start))
    return()
  }
}
```

this is what I get when I try to run it:

```
plot.medals2('USA',1933,1456,c('GOLD'))
NULL
```

I tried to use the breakpoint option to see what is going on and it seems the 
function does enter the if statement meaning it recognizes that the variable start is larger than finish but then for some reason it skips the next 2 rows and does not plot anything. Now when I use this

```
 ggplot() + ylab('medals won') + xlab('year') +
   ggtitle(paste('Medals by',"",countries.df[countries.df$country_id==code,]$country_name,',',"",finish,'-',start))
```

outside of a function it works but not when its a part of a function.

Comment: it'd prbly help if `return()` actually returned something. also, your function is missing a closing `}`

Comment: It should work if you wrap the `ggplot` or plotting object in `print`.

Comment: it looks like you never declare any `data` for your `ggplot()` function, and also never declare any `aes`thetics. So... I am not sure what you thought would show up. You're not telling it to plot anything.